# Problemas accediento al localhost

Tags: apache, spring

Hol a todo el mundo !

Hace poco pasé el Ccleaner por el PC y cuando inicio la aplicacion con spring me salta lo siguiente , no tengo nada con el IIS ,puede ser que sean por problemas con puertos o algo por el estilo ? Es que por mas que busco por internt no encuentro solución al problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siento no poder dar más informacion , cualquier ayuda es de agredecer pero me tiene loco este error.

Comment: Estás usando apache en ubuntu o mediante un XAMPP/similares ?

Comment: Utilizo windows y estoy utilizando xamp para mysql